# Top Tab Navigator height problem when wrapped in ScrollView

Tags: javascript, android, css, react-native, scrollview

I have this basic [Tab component](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/) wrapped in a ScrollView:

```js
    const MyTab = () => {
return (
        <ScrollView>
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <Tab.Navigator  
                    initialRouteName="GeneralInformations"
                >
                    <Tab.Screen name="GeneralInformations" component={LoremIpsum} />
                    <Tab.Screen name="TransactionsTab" component={LoremIpsum} />
                </Tab.Navigator>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    )
}
```

Each screen have this basic View component:

```js
    const LoremIpsum = () => (
        <View>
            <Text>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc fermentum augue a mi semper, et aliquet arcu tempor. Suspendisse ante nunc, iaculis quis purus nec, consectetur molestie nibh. Etiam non ex facilisis, placerat erat vitae, blandit eros. Pellentesque ac posuere urna. Vivamus tempor diam a condimentum gravida. Ut et placerat justo. Duis a rutrum odio. Nulla sed dolor rhoncus, vestibulum velit eget, cursus neque. Nulla facilisi. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque interdum magna a fermentum efficitur. Nunc non tellus vitae leo luctus dignissim.

Integer laoreet suscipit sem id ullamcorper. Aliquam euismod sodales nisl sit amet imperdiet. Praesent fermentum magna tellus, nec tristique quam fringilla sit amet. Sed ut risus non urna congue maximus. Sed eros leo, dictum eget metus vitae, laoreet porttitor leo. Nullam sed lacinia neque. Nulla facilisi. Vestibulum vel aliquam elit, et faucibus lorem. Sed sit amet tincidunt eros.

Proin imperdiet orci vel accumsan pharetra. Quisque nec lorem nec purus cursus feugiat at ac lorem. Sed luctus porttitor ante, a mollis dui facilisis non. Mauris venenatis ultricies nisi sed ornare. In a volutpat ex. Quisque at arcu a ante vestibulum pellentesque. Morbi eu semper sem, eu imperdiet odio. Etiam non eleifend ligula. Phasellus gravida tellus a ligula efficitur feugiat. Nulla ligula mauris, consequat ac mollis in, tincidunt aliquet sapien. Suspendisse ultricies quam ac velit ultricies mattis.

Sed dictum semper pellentesque. Donec ultricies diam a justo consectetur tincidunt. Fusce cursus dignissim nisi. Aliquam ut commodo nulla, non fringilla risus. Donec egestas massa et ligula accumsan, at condimentum ex pellentesque. In non interdum sapien, sed efficitur libero. Nulla eu neque eleifend, sodales risus ac, dictum sapien. Sed molestie quam sit amet lacinia vehicula. Suspendisse pellentesque maximus libero quis laoreet. Sed vel nisl non magna feugiat lobortis. Proin ac dui sit amet dolor pulvinar placerat. Nam quis sem eu mi vulputate ornare. In rhoncus nunc vitae nibh fringilla maximus.

Nullam ornare volutpat vulputate. Praesent quis purus sem. Duis facilisis, ipsum sit amet efficitur finibus, turpis velit molestie sapien, eget commodo sapien nisi et massa. In enim mauris, sollicitudin eu est non, elementum mollis turpis. Maecenas mauris magna, sodales sed odio sit amet, consequat feugiat sapien. Cras blandit non massa non dictum. Vestibulum finibus eu felis sed sollicitudin. Aliquam dignissim semper felis, vel lacinia augue egestas nec. Curabitur gravida, lacus non mattis mattis, lectus leo lacinia ante, eu laoreet erat sem ut ex. Fusce ante orci, aliquet nec mi ac, tincidunt semper est. Quisque lobortis, ante viverra lacinia gravida, ipsum nisl ornare enim, vitae sollicitudin libero tellus nec ligula. Cras ultrices metus eget ex faucibus, sed sodales est pretium. Cras ac purus enim. Sed dui dolor, porttitor non odio vel, efficitur sagittis diam. Mauris malesuada libero vitae purus rhoncus ornare. Quisque turpis mi, ullamcorper eget felis ac, molestie aliquam lectus.

Maecenas nulla lacus, ornare vitae mauris ut, placerat porta augue. Mauris eget ullamcorper tellus. Mauris accumsan lacus eu diam tincidunt tincidunt. Vestibulum accumsan ultricies purus, nec pretium eros ultrices ut. Morbi facilisis at est vel hendrerit. Nunc justo orci, tincidunt in condimentum eu, consectetur quis tortor. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus sit amet sem varius, convallis ante non, semper mauris. Maecenas aliquet aliquet justo, a aliquam nunc. Suspendisse dignissim, tortor nec imperdiet condimentum, mauris purus malesuada enim, at mattis arcu felis at dui. Maecenas vitae lacus tincidunt, commodo massa ut, feugiat diam. Nam elementum quam vitae enim rhoncus tempor. Phasellus sit amet placerat quam. Cras dolor erat, sollicitudin a metus vel, aliquet commodo neque.

Cras vel pellentesque ipsum. Fusce et dictum augue. Quisque vulputate in purus quis molestie. Proin id nunc aliquet, blandit tortor ut, tristique lectus. Aliquam malesuada nulla a leo varius ullamcorper. Nam aliquet semper lorem et vestibulum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vivamus sagittis, mauris id lobortis mattis, ligula ante tincidunt nisi, sodales imperdiet leo mi et nisl. Curabitur consectetur mollis tortor, ut tincidunt augue aliquet sed.
            </Text>
            </View>
    )
```

But the default behavior is that the components don't show up:

[image: Tab Navigator without height setted]

However, if I manually set the `height` of the parent `View` (that wraps my Tab.Navigator component) the components starts to show up, but not the entire component, just as much as the height value. Ex, if I set `height:500`:

[image]

Set `height:'100%'` also doesn't work either because it only shows up to the height of the screen, but the component is bigger than it.

I need to show the entire `LoremIpsum` component, and I need the ScrollView to work. The only way I got it is by manually setting the `height` (as I said before) but I want to use components with different heights.

I really need to use this ScrollView parent... anyone know what is this?

Comment: Are you sure you want the tab navigator inside the ScrollView?  Either way, have you tried setting `contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}` on the ScrollView?

Comment: I'm using a component to create scrollable header (https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-image-header-scroll-view), which automatically wraps the content in a scrollview, so I really wanna make this works. There's something wrong with doing this? I don't get what's the problem by using this Tab Navigator inside a ScrollView. This `FlexGrow` solution doesn't work either